# How to share data from one view to another?

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, view

I have some problems with simple variable sharing between different views.

I have first main view called **MainPage.xaml** and second called **Page2.xaml**.

I want to check which radiobutton on **MainPage.xaml** is checked and send a variable with that date to **Page2.xaml**.

**MainPage:**

```
namespace IDG
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {


        public string choice;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void bt_start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (rb_choice1.IsChecked == true)
            {
                choice = "choice1";

            }

            if (rb_quiz.IsChecked == true)
            {
                this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2), choice);

            }

        }
    }
}
```

**And Page2:**

```
namespace IDG
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class Page2 : Page
    {

        private string x;

        public Page2()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

        }



        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
       {
            var param = e.Parameter as string;
            x = param;
            textBlock1.Text = x;
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
        }
    }
}
```

And I want this parameter to be stored in main class, how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On **Page 2** in the `OnNavigatedTo` event retreive the value like this: `var param = e.Parameter as string`

**EDIT**

Assign the retreived parameter to the textblock in the OnNavigatedTo. At the time the page is constructed the value of x is "".

```
public sealed partial class Page2 : Page
{

    private string x="";

    public Page2()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }



    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        x = e.Parameter as string;
        textBlock1.Text = x;
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but how exactly use it protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            string passedParameter = e.Parameter.ToString();
            x = passedParameter;
        }

Comment: Almost correct, just replace the body of that function with the one-liner I posted ;)

Comment: Ok, but how to acces this variable param outside this method? I have var param = e.Parameter as string;
            x = param; and I can't access either x or param variable outside this method?

Comment: Assign it to a global variable than! private string myGlobalParam. Place it somewhere outside the onNavigatedTo function.

Comment: I already have but it doesn't work either. Maybe I have to initialize this method somewhere? Can you look at my code? I have upadated it.

Comment: After x= param assign the value to the textblock. You assign x to the textblock in the constructor which isn't good because at the time the page is constructed x is empty. Get it?

Comment: The assignment to texblock works now (inside method) but I'm not sure if it's assigned to x variable in the main constructor method. How to store this variable in main class? I need to use it. Because everytime I will use it in constructor the x variable will be empty?

Comment: Thanks but in main method the x is still "". Or am I supposed to write the entire code in "OnNavigatedTo" method?

Comment: Ok I give up I don't know what you're trying to achieve, sorry. Be more specific next time

Comment: Ok let's give it a try again. So what is your "main method" exactly? Is it in Page2? If so, than x is available in that method.

Comment: I'm completely new to C# so please forgive my "c++ kind of thinking". "public Page2()" is some kind of main method loaded on the start of the view and I should initialize my other methods here? Because whatever I do inside this "public Page2" the value of "x" variable is still "" as declared globally before this method.

Comment: Oh I see. Page2() is the page's constructor. You can intialize variables in that. In c# you don't have to init methods like you would do in a c++ header. Just place your method anywhere inside the Page2 class and call wherever you want in Page2

Comment: But note that you can get the parameter in OnNavigatedTo and should call your method inside OnNavigatedTo if you want to do something with that value immediately

Comment: Thanks, now I partly understand. I have created another method with "x" as a parameter and called it inside "OnNavigatedTo" method and now it works good and x value is "updated". But globally x is still "". What If I want to daclare another global variable and assign it x value to it? It will be still "" (as initialized) outside "OnNavigatedTo" and the method I have created. If my question is too confusing for you I'm really grateful for your help anyway :)

Comment: Globally actually means globally in Page2. You can't get it outside Page2 if this is your question. But in Page2 x is available from anywhere! :)

Comment: But if you got the value on Page2 could you please accept my answer? Because that already helped I guess..

Comment: Sure thing! Many thanks for your help and have a nice day! :)

Comment: Thanks, you too! I hope you'll figure it out anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I'm working on WPF project but we use it with DevExpress library, and for your issue, it's very easy to be fixed with Messenger in DevExpress.

We just register the messenger where you want to receive the data,

```
public class Message {
    //... 
}
public class Recipient {
    public Recipient() {
        Messenger.Default.Register<string>(this, OnMessage1);
        Messenger.Default.Register<Message>(this, OnMessage2);
    }
    void SendMessages() {
        Messenger.Default.Send("test");
        Messenger.Default.Send(new Message());
    }
    void OnMessage1(string message) {
        //... 
    }
    void OnMessage2(Message message) {
        //... 
    }
}
```

And then you can send it from another view,

```
public class InheritedMessage : Message {
    //... 
}
public class Recipient {
    public Recipient() {
        //Inherited messages are not processed with this subscription 
        Messenger.Default.Register<Message>(
            recipient: this, 
            action: OnMessage);
        //Inherited messages are processed with this subscription 
        Messenger.Default.Register<Message>(
            recipient: this, 
            receiveInheritedMessagesToo: true,
            action: OnMessage);
    }
    void SendMessages() {
        Messenger.Default.Send(new Message());
        Messenger.Default.Send(new InheritedMessage());
    }
    void OnMessage(Message message) {
        //... 
    }
}
```

With it, you can pass data between modules (or views, but recommend to use MVVM)
If you want to know more about DevExpress, please go through https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument17474

Hope it could help you. :)

Comment: Thank you Jacob :)